# Different pipe pressure on motorcycle exhaust

Tags: motorcycle, exhaust

I've looked everywhere for an answer, but without success.

My problem is this:

When my v-twin, twin-exhaust motorcycle is at idle, there is a significant difference in the pressure experienced by a hand placed at the end of one pipe, compared with the other one.

Each of the two cylinders has TWO spark plugs, presumably to aid combustion.

What are the possible causes of the pressure difference?

Is there perhaps only one cause - that one cylinder isn't firing at all?

Please help!

Comment: Putting your hand over the exhausts isn't exactly a scientific method, are you _sure_ that the pressure are _discernibly_ different? Have you asked a couple of other guys if they can feel a difference, without biasing them by directly asking if they can feel a difference in pressure?

Comment: Can you share the make/model/year of your bike along with if you have a OEM headers and exhaust or an OEM/stock exhaust.  Thanks, cheers and welcome to the site!!!

Comment: if only one cylinder is firing it wont be anywhere near as hot as the other, CAREFULLY place your hand near each cylinder when the engine is running to see which is hotter, or use an infrared/laser thermometer.

Comment: @James Trotter, There is a difference in pressure so great that you don't need to ask a friend, honestly. One cylinder pushes you hand away like a gale while the other one doesn't move your hand. Does this help you to give me an answer, please?

Comment: @Tapster That's fair enough, that's what i was asking. Sometimes it easy to get an idea stuck in your head, and it helps to take a step back and look at it again - at least from my experience. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @DucatiKiller, Thanks for the welcome! It's a chopper. The engine is from a Honda NT650 twin from 9 or 10 years ago. It has been bored-out to 700cc and has high-compression pistons. It has a Harley CV carb and non-stock air filter. It has drag pipes and is in a very soft state of tune, being more a shower than a goer, however it it lovely to ride!

Comment: @James Trotter, thanks. Does this difference in pressure make you think of any particular, obvious diagnosis? Cheers.

Comment: @Mauro, thank you for the suggestion, so obvious that I completely didn't think of it!! I'll try that, and check the plugs and ignition. That should sort it out.

Answer (score 1):

Check that there isn't a crossover pipe in the exhaust system, if one pipe is slightly more restricted than the other this may cause that issue. Is the bike running ok?

If you are concerned something is wrong and the bike is perhaps not running as it should firstly do a compression test on the cylinders just to make sure everything is ok there.

If cylinder pressures are ok remove exhausts and check for any restrictions in the baffle sections, or if you have any sort of flow valves in the exhaust system check that they're working as they should.